# Permitting an unsafe script in a Rails development environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, http-headers

In a development environment, I'd like to allow `script-src unsafe-inline` in a Rails app. I'm trying to use the [heavens_door](https://github.com/amatsuda/heavens_door/issues/26) gem, to produce system tests.

> customizing content security policy on content security policy initializer.

It's OK for it to be unsafe, as the server is the local Rails server, but how can I configure my Rails app to allow it?

- https://github.com/amatsuda/heavens_door/issues/26

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have all Javascript code in separately loaded .js files. Then you can add trusted origins to the content security policy in an initializer like for example `config/initializers/csp.rb` like this:

```
my_custom_script_sources = ["https://kit.fontawesome.com", "http://localhost:3000"]
Rails.application.config.content_security_policy do |policy|
  policy.script_src(:self, *my_custom_script_sources)
end
```

You can of course check for `Rails.env` and set the custom script sources accordingly so you don't disclose your internal development urls in production.

Also you can add `:unsafe_inline` to any policy element, but you should probably not. It's a lot more secure to explicitly list your sources than to allow any inline script to run that would eliminate protection from XSS. You might want to accept the risk of `:unsafe_inline` though if you have no way to change a 3rd party component to not use inline Javascript. I don't know `heavens_door` unfortunately, I'm not sure whether that is the case or not.

You can use [this tool](https://csp-evaluator.withgoogle.com/) for example to evaluate your CSP against best practices.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Gabor, I will probably have to hack the gem to make that work. It should be noted that this is only running against my local development environment, so it can be completely insecure.

Comment: Is there some simple way to whitelist all js, so that this code will run without needing to hack the gem?

Comment: @ardochhigh On a controller (or `ApplicationController` itself) you can do `content_security_policy false` to disable the CSP header altogether, but be careful with this, the app should not go into production with CSP disabled, if it is only necessary for testing. :)

Comment: Alternatively, you can also set `Rails.application.config.content_security_policy_report_only = true` in an initializer to use a non-blocking policy. This is usually done to migrate legacy apps.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to Gabor Lengyel for the solution. In summary, you just need to add this line to the `ApplicationController`

```rb
content_security_policy false
```

Ensure it is not committed and pushed to production!

Comment: I understand for you it's testing and that's ok, but for other future readers, in a real production version of an application you should not disable CSP unless necessary, and then you should understand the implications.